# How can I crop out the region inside the white border rectangle in an image, using Python?

Tags: python, image-processing

apologies if this question is a repeat but I tried searching a lot on stackexchange for a similar solution but couldn't find one.

Here is my image: [image with a rectangle around my ROI with a white border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttLT2.jpg)

I want to use Python libraries like OpenCV and/or matplotlib to automatically identify the white border box and then crop and save it as a separate .jpg image file. How can I do this? I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: If you drew the rectangle, then you should have the coordinates already. If someone else drew the rectangle, then tell them to a) give you the coordinates, b) remove that white border around the rust-colored square image, and c) use a lossless image format instead of jpeg. You *could* find the coordinates of the white rectangle in *this* image using thresholding, but you should be getting higher-quality inputs to process.

Comment: do you draw this rectangle? If you draw then you should already have coordinates. And if you have image as numpy array then you can crop `array[ start_row:end_row , start_column:end_column ]`

Comment: matplotlib is for plotting, not for finding things in pictures. [edit] your question and show that your searches _did_ find and why you couldn't use that to solve your problem. please take the [tour], review [ask]